# Why does putting field theory on $S^4$ deform the scalar kinetic term?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I was reading the famous [localization paper by Pestun](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2824), where he proves, among other things, that $\mathcal{N}=4$ super Yang-Mills (SYM) on $S^4$ localizes to a Gaussian matrix model. However, I was caught up on a seemingly trivial statement about taking the $\mathcal{N}=4$ theory on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and putting it on the 4-sphere $S^4$, in section 2 on page 9:

> Because of the curvature, the kinetic term for the scalar fields is deformed as
> $(\partial\Phi)^2\to (\partial\Phi)^2+\frac{R}{6}\Phi^2$, where $R$ is the scalar curvature.

He goes on to justify this as:

> This can be derived from the conformal invariance; one can check that $\int \mathrm{d}^4x\,\sqrt{g}((\partial\Phi)^2+\frac{R}{6}\Phi^2)$ is invariant under
> Weyl transformations of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}\to e^{2\Omega}g_{\mu\nu}$ and scalar fields $\Phi\to e^{−\Omega}\Phi$.

I don't really understand where this justification comes from. Is it because $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM is conformal in flat space, so we demand that all the symmetries are preserved when we change to a curved background? Or is it something more subtle? Also, why are only the scalar fields affected? Shouldn't I expect corrections to the vector fields and spinor fields as well?

Comment: We expect the decompactification limit to be smooth, so the symmetries of the decompactified theory such as scale invariance must be preserved if you're to approximate $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a sufficiently large $S^4$.

Comment: Well, the idea is that you expect that $N=4$ SYM is conformally-invariant in the sense that if you want to put it on a manifold $M$, you do not need the Riemann structure of $M$, but only the conformal structure. This is the same as to say that you want the Lagrangian to be Weyl-invariant. With gauge fields you don't need such modifications because things like $F$ are defined without metric structure (only differential structure is needed for external derivative), and the kinetic term is Weyl-invariant for a fairly simple reason. For fermions you have to check Weyl props of Dirac operator.

Comment: (I'm ignoring spin structure, anomalies, etc. in my comment above.)